# SetError on TextInputLayout not available

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to show validation messages on TextInputLayouts. I should be able to just do this (as with native android):

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);
til.setErrorEnabled(true);
til.setError("You need to enter a name");
```

But it seems like setError method is not available for xamarin? For EditText the setError is available, but don't want that. e.g:

```
TextInputLayout txtI_password = FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.input_layout_password);
txtI_password. ?????
```

Using:

```
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, property setters are accessed directly, not through a function.

```
til.ErrorEnabled = true;
til.Error = "You need to enter a name"
```